# Why can´t I connect to my localhost with https?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi everyone I try to connect my node.js project in to my localhost server but I can´t.

My Code in app.js:

```
var bufferkey = require('fs').readFileSync("sslcert/key.pem");
var buffercert = require('fs').readFileSync("sslcert/cert.pem");
MongoClient.connect(config.database, {
    sslKey: bufferkey,
    sslCert: buffercert,
    sslValidate: false //in case of self-generated certificate
},
    function(err, db) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(db);
    db.close();
    },{
    //useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
   .then(() => {
       console.log('Database connected successfully ' + config.database);
   }).catch(err => {
       console.log(err);
   });
```

config/database.js:

```
module.exports = {
    database: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/gamerforum?ssl=true',
    secret: 'secrets'
}
```

I do not have any errors but now I can´t go on Port 5000 with https .. why ?

```
(node:24186) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Server started on port 5000
Database connected successfully mongodb://localhost:27017/gamerforum
```

Comment: Whether you .pem files starts with -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----. Log bufferkey and  buffercert and check what did you get.

Comment: yes.. what do I have to change ? :)

Comment: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/tutorials/connect/ssl/ - pls check here. Hope it may help. In my code I have useNewUrlParser: true param (tbh - copy-paste)

Comment: I changed it this way and add ?ssl=true behind my url but then I got a MongoNetworkError :/

Comment: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established...